# When I type in terminal: export JDK_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/", where does it get stored?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have tried multiple locations, but with no luck of finding where was it added:

- **.bashrc**
- **.bash_profile**
- **/etc/profile**
- **/etc/environment**
- **.profile**

When I do `echo $JDK_HOME`, I get what I expect `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/`, but I am dying to know where is it located? (in case I'd like to change it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`export` only stores that variable in RAM. The `export` keyword just tells your shell to copy that into the environment of any new programs that it runs.

If you want it to be permanent, add that line to the end of `~/.bashrc`